# JBehave ambiguous step

Tags: java, ambiguity, jbehave

Say I have:

```
@Given("first name is $firstName")
@Given("first name is $firstName and last name is $lastName")
```

The following step would be marked as ambiguous:

```
Given first name is John and last name is Smith
```

Without using quotes to surround the first parameter, how can I fix this step so it only matches the second one?  Using quotes to surround both the parameters separately also has the same ambiguity issue.

Is there a limit on how long each parameter is?  Are there certain characters that can't be passed in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this by using step priorities, as documented here: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/prioritising-steps.html

Your problem would be solved by setting a higher priority to the variant with two parameters:

```
@Given("first name is $firstName")
@Given(value = "first name is $firstName and last name is $lastName", priority = 1)
```

I tried your example and with this combination, the two steps were separated.

(Edit: my initial solution had quotes for the parameters, but it works without as well)

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about step priorities.  This will come in very handy. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this scenario can be write this way:

```
Given first name is John
And last name is Smith
```

And the steps:

```
@Given("first name is $firstName")
@And("last name is $lastName")
```

You can create the person object first an set the name and the last name in the "@Given" steps.
If you need add another property, like email, you just need create another step:

```
@And("the email is $email")
public addEmail(String email) {
    person.setEmail(email);
}
```

So this problem not gonna happen and you code will be more reusable.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that was a bad simplification of an example of what I wanted.

Let me try to rephrase it better:

    @Given("a person with first name $firstName")
    @Given("a person with first name $firstName and last name $lastName")

where calling these steps would create new person objects.

Then the following step would be marked as ambiguous:
    Given a person with first name John and last name Smith

It could either parse it as creating a person with first name "John and last name Smith" or first name "John" and last name "Smith".

Comment: You dont need create the object in all "Given" steps, you can store the name and last name in attributes and in the "When" step create the object. I use this (similar) in [example](http://github.com/piantino/automated-traceability-example/blob/master/scrumforge-acceptance-test-jbehave/src/test/java/org/scrumforge/acceptance/test/CreateUserStoryTest.java) with this [scenarios](https://github.com/piantino/automated-traceability-example/blob/master/scrumforge-acceptance-test-jbehave/src/test/resources/stories/manage_resources/scrum_team/CreateUser.story). I think this approach is more reusable.

Comment: Yeah, I understood how I could split it into separate steps to make it work, but I wanted to see if there was a way I could keep it as one step because I want to create a lot of objects, with certain attributes set as needed.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was substituting ankle brackets (<>) for the dollar sign ($), i.e.

```
@Given("a person with first name <firstName>")
```

and

```
@Given("a person with first name <firstName> and last name <lastName>")
```